# Prevent html5 video from preloading in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, video

I have a wordpress page with lots of videos and would like to stop the preload with html5. I am inserting the videos with the featured media options. Therefore I cannot add the attribute preload="none" to my video-tag.

So I was trying to manage it with javascript, like:

```
function videoPreload () {
    document.getElementsByTagName('video').setAttribute('preload', 'none');
};
videoPreload();
```

But it doesn't work. I get the error, that this function does not exist. How can I add the relevant attribute to stop the videos from preloading?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `document.getElementsByTagName` returns an array of all video elements.

I would change your code to either reference a single video

```
document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].setAttribute('preload', 'none');
```

or add an id to your video element and reference that.

```
document.getElementById("myVid").setAttribute('preload', 'none');
```

Also, it's worth noting that the preload attribute does not work in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. So ... it's not a good solution to have few videos on one webpage. I think it would be better to replace the video with a thumbnail, so the video will only be loaded when the user clicks on the image.